# Create Icon for window in python without putting icon in same directory

Tags: python, icons, directory

I run this code:

```
self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('4.png'))
```

and it works because `4.png` is in working folder. But if I put `4.png` to `"D:\\Sculptris\models"` and run this code:

```
self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('D:\\Sculptris\models\4.png'))
```

the window appears with default window icon. Can someone help me please?

Comment: use raw prefix: `r'D:\Sculptris\models\4.png'`. `\4` is seen as binary 4

Comment: better: if python program is there, use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` so you don't have to hardcode the dir